# How how count rows between two dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table with columns index(sometimes changes to B) ,price and pricedate. I want to add column counts, which shows the number of working day in the specific month

[image]

I tried following code, however it shows that the column price should be also grouped. I tried select without price column, however in counta column I got only 1 for each of the dates. Do you know how to fix the problem and have the result as in the table above?

```
select priceindex, price, pricedate ,count(pricedate) as counta --, price
from myDB
and pricedate between date_trunc('month',pricedate) and pricedate + interval '1 day'
group by index, pricedate
```

Comment: How do you know what days are working days?  Are you just enumerating the rows or is there something fancier going on?

Answer (score 1):

If the pricedate data has no duplicates, you don't need the group by. If there are duplicate values for pricedate, then you DO need a group by, but the question is: what do you want to happen to the price when you group by pricedate, since there may be 2 different prices for the same date?
e.g.

```
price  pricedate
6      06.05.2020
4      06.05.2020
```

in this scenario, which price do you want, 4 or 6? A good answer might be the average:

```
select index, avg(price), pricedate, count(pricedate) as counta
from myDB
where pricedate between date_trunc('month',pricedate) and pricedate + interval '1 day'
group by index, pricedate
```

Other options are min(price), max(price) etc. If all the prices are the same, then min() max() and avg() will return the same value> Some databases have first() which returns a value from any row the database considers to be 'first' (and depending on the database, this may not be helpful).
--edit--
If you use count(pricedate) and 'group by pricedate' then you will only ever get a count of 1. Perhaps you have misunderstood the 'between' clause (which is used to limit data, not to calculate the difference between dates).
try

```
select (pricedate - date_trunc('month',pricedate)) as counta
```

(no group by at this time) and see if that gives you a closer answer.

Comment: Hello, I have unique dates. The only variable that should be grouped by your logic is index (here it shows only A, in reality A:D). And the same as in the previous comment, unfortunately, I have only 1 values in column counta.

Answer (score 1):

Always bring your data as plain text, not in an image, so we all can copy/paste.

I took a total of 15 minutes to re-type your input data and re-format it.

But, now I have it:

What you need is the running sum of: 1 if it's a week day, 0 if it's a week-end-day, per month. That's plain vanilla OLAP , window function, functionality. Welcome to SQL-99 ...

Here goes.

The input:

```
WITH
-- your input as in-line table, typed manually ...
input(index,price,pricedate,counta_in) AS (
          SELECT 'A',NULL::INT,DATE '2020-05-01', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        5,DATE '2020-05-04', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        4,DATE '2020-05-05', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        6,DATE '2020-05-06', 4
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        4,DATE '2020-05-07', 5
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        4,DATE '2020-05-11', 6
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        6,DATE '2020-05-12', 7
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        7,DATE '2020-05-13', 8
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        8,DATE '2020-05-14', 9
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        8,DATE '2020-05-15',10
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        8,DATE '2020-05-18',11
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        4,DATE '2020-05-19',12
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        5,DATE '2020-05-20',13
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        3,DATE '2020-05-21',14
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        5,DATE '2020-05-22',15
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        4,DATE '2020-05-26',16
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        5,DATE '2020-05-27',17
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        3,DATE '2020-05-28',18
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        5,DATE '2020-05-29',19
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        4,DATE '2020-06-01', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        6,DATE '2020-06-02', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        4,DATE '2020-06-03', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        4,DATE '2020-06-04', 4
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        5,DATE '2020-06-05', 5
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        4,DATE '2020-06-08', 6
UNION ALL SELECT 'A',        6,DATE '2020-06-09', 7
)
```

The actual select, selecting from the input above:

```
-- acutal query starts here. counta_out is my OLAP expression.
SELECT
  *
, SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK_ISO(pricedate) < 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(pricedate) ORDER BY pricedate) 
  AS counta_out
FROM input;
```

And the result, including control column and result column:

```
index | price | pricedate  | counta_in | counta_out 
------+-------+------------+-----------+------------
A     |       | 2020-05-01 |         1 |          1
A     |     5 | 2020-05-04 |         2 |          2
A     |     4 | 2020-05-05 |         3 |          3
A     |     6 | 2020-05-06 |         4 |          4
A     |     4 | 2020-05-07 |         5 |          5
A     |     4 | 2020-05-11 |         6 |          6
A     |     6 | 2020-05-12 |         7 |          7
A     |     7 | 2020-05-13 |         8 |          8
A     |     8 | 2020-05-14 |         9 |          9
A     |     8 | 2020-05-15 |        10 |         10
A     |     8 | 2020-05-18 |        11 |         11
A     |     4 | 2020-05-19 |        12 |         12
A     |     5 | 2020-05-20 |        13 |         13
A     |     3 | 2020-05-21 |        14 |         14
A     |     5 | 2020-05-22 |        15 |         15
A     |     4 | 2020-05-26 |        16 |         16
A     |     5 | 2020-05-27 |        17 |         17
A     |     3 | 2020-05-28 |        18 |         18
A     |     5 | 2020-05-29 |        19 |         19
A     |     4 | 2020-06-01 |         1 |          1
A     |     6 | 2020-06-02 |         2 |          2
A     |     4 | 2020-06-03 |         3 |          3
A     |     4 | 2020-06-04 |         4 |          4
A     |     5 | 2020-06-05 |         5 |          5
A     |     4 | 2020-06-08 |         6 |          6
A     |     6 | 2020-06-09 |         7 |          7
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use clause GROUP BY, you need to specify all columns used in SELECT.
Then the query is

```
SELECT priceindex, price, pricedate, count(pricedate) AS counta
FROM myDB
WHERE pricedate BETWEEN date_trunc('month',pricedate) and pricedate + interval '1 day'
GROUP BY priceindex, price, pricedate
```

You can also try the clause DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY.

```
SELECT DISTINCT priceindex, price, pricedate, count(pricedate) AS counta
FROM myDB 
WHERE pricedate BETWEEN date_trunc('month',pricedate) and pricedate + interval '1 day'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added price column, however, in the end, I have the same result that in column counts all numbers are 1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT priceindex, price, pricedate
        , row_number() OVER
                (PARTITION BY priceindex, date_trunc('month', pricedate)
                ORDER BY pricedate) AS counta 
FROM myDB
        ;
```